# Cannot display reads for multiple .fastq.gz files using for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, echo

ok so I am still very new at using the bash terminal and i'm having this issue. I have a bunch of .fastq.gz files and I just wanted to display on screen how many reads each individual in the folder contains so I wrote this loop:

```
for i in /Data/ 
do  
    reads=$(zcat *.fastq.gz | wc -l)
    echo "$i =  ${reads} reads" 
done
```

However, when i run it my output is just:

```
/Data/ =   59182360 reads
```

I think it's actually just giving me the total reads in all the files in the folder. 
Any insights into what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what "fastq" is.  What's inside these files?  An example of the data, along with an external reference as to what this format is generated by would be helpful. Otherwise, all I know is that you're counting the lines of what may be a compressed text file.

Comment: Read a bash tutorial. There is no such thing as `for i in /Data/` to iterate through subitems of `/Data/`. `/Data/` is just a token like `foo`, so this loop is just a joke. Use `/Data/*`, and you'll also have to provide the full path in `zcat` or `cd` (not recommended).